# use debugger on a .m function from matlab workspace in simulink

Tags: matlab, function, debugging, simulink, workspace

I am running Simulink and have a MatlabFunctionblock to write my own code. In this function I would like to call other functions from my matlab workspace.

I can do so using the line :

```
coder.extrinsic('name_of_Function_in_workspace.m')
```

and call the workspace function in the block with :

```
[out_variable] = name_of_Function_in_workspace(in_variable)
```

However, "the code generator produces code for the call to an extrinsic function, but does not produce the function's internal code" (from mathworks)

Therefore I cannot use the debugger and the break points are not took in account.

**Is there any way to use the debugger by tuning parameters ? Or do you have an other method than to use coder.extrinsic ?**

Any help would be gladly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: You can definitely set breakpoints within `name_of_Function_in_workspace` and the model will pause at those breakpoints allowing you to step through the code.  What do you mean when you ask "use the debugger by tuning parameters"?  Using the debugger and parameter tuning are two different things.

Comment: Thank you for your response, you are rigth, I tried to create a simple simulink model, the breakpoint were reached.
However, In my global model, the breakpoint were still not reached...

I found after some frustration where the problem comes:
I had created many version by duplicating folder containing the Simulink model but also the function. And didn't changes the functions name for each version.

By putting a breaking point on each function with the same name in each versions folder, the breaking point reached a function in another versions folder...

I will create a single library.